# Como posso procurar uma propriedade se eu não sei o nome dela?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb

Na minha base de dados `mongodb` estou a guardar um documento com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
    "_id": "A/B",
    "Properties": {
        "Abandoned": {
            "TypeName": "int",
            "Name": "A/B/Abandoned",
            "Value": 2
        },
        "Busy": {
            "TypeName": "byte[]",
            "Name": "A/B/Busy",
            "Value": "<bynarydata>"
        }
    }
}
```

As propriedades não tem um nome conhecido e por isso não posso navegar por elas, ou seja, não posso usar `Properties.Abandoned` (por exemplo)

Eu gostava de obter todas as propriedades cujo `TypeName` não seja `byte[]`. Tem forma de fazer isso?

Para clarificar: No documento que dei como exemplo queria obter apenas a propriedade `Abandoned`.

Comment: Aceito soluções com um esquema ligeiramente diferente. Desde que a mudança esteja explicada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que vou resolver o problema metendo as propriedades `byte[]` numa zona diferente do documento. Dessa forma posso fazer uma simples projeção para obter apenas as propriedades não binárias. O documento fica com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
    "_id": "A/B",
    "Properties": {
        "Abandoned": {
            "TypeName": "int",
            "Name": "A/B/Abandoned",
            "Value": 2
        }
    },
    "ByteProperties": {
        "Busy" : {
            "TypeName": "byte[]",
            "Name": "A/B/Busy",
            "Value": "<bynarydata>"
        }
    }
}
```